# Python Outputting Text in Hex

Tags: python-2.7

I'm working with a very large text file (58GB) that I'm attempting to split into smaller chunks. The problem that I'm running into is that the smaller chunks appear to be Hex. I'm having my terminal print each line to stdout as well, but when I'm seeing it printed in stdout it's looking like normal strings to me. Is this known behavior? I've never encountered an issue where Python keeps spitting stuff out in Hex before. Even odder when I tried using Ubuntu's split from the command line it was *also* generating everything in Hex.

Code snippet below:

```
working_dir = '/SECRET/'

output_dir  = path.join(working_dir, 'output')

test_file = 'SECRET.txt'

report_file = 'SECRET_REPORT.txt'

output_chunks = 100000000

output_base   = 'SECRET'

input         = open(test_file, 'r')
report_output = open(report_file, 'w')

count   = 0
at_line = 0
output_f = None

for line in input:
    if count % output_chunks == 0:
        if output_f:
            report_output.write('[{}] wrote {} lines to {}. Total count is {}'.format(
                datetime.now(), output_chunks, str(output_base + str(at_line) + '.txt'), count))
            output_f.close()

        output_f = open('{}{}.txt'.format(output_base, str(at_line)), 'wb')
        at_line += 1
    output_f.write(line.encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
    print line.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
    count += 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what was going on:

Each line was started with a NUL character. When I was opening up parts of the file using head or PyCharm's terminal it was showing up normal, but when I was looking at my output in Sublime Text it was picking up on that NUL character and rendering the results in Hex. I had to strip '\x00' from each line of the output and it started looking the way I would expect it to